# Starting and stopping systemd services with OnCalendar for a period of time, every day

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, systemd, daemon, timer

I have a two services (a video player and an image recognition daemon) that I want to start at 9am and finish running at 23pm every day (as well as on boot, although the system is going to be running continuously). For each service I created a `-startup.service` and a `-shutdown.service`. The services are combined in a `daemon-on.target` and a `daemon-off.target` which are then triggered by `daemon-on.timer` and `daemon-off.timer` respectively.

After a few attempts and tests I discovered that timers initially trigger the targets as expected but the go into the state with NEXT time being set to n/a.

This is an awful lot of work just to get two applications running with a timer. I'm sure it's missing something plain obvious and would appreciate any tips!

mpv-startup.service starts the video player service:

```
[Unit]
Description=MPV Video Player Startup
After=xorg.target
Requires=xorg.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/videoplayer/app.py
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
Also=daemon-on.timer
```

recog-startup.service starts the image recognition service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Recog Startup Service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/recog
ExecStart=/opt/recog/recog run
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
Also=daemon-on.timer
```

mpv-shutdown.service stops the video player service as a oneshot command

```
[Unit]
Description=MPV Video Player Shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --user stop mpv-startup.service

[Install]
Also=daemon-off.timer
```

recog-shutdown.service stops the image recognition service as a oneshot command:

```
[Unit]
Description=Recog Shutdown Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --user stop recog-startup.service

[Install]
Also=daemon-off.timer
```

daemon-on.target combines two startup services above and is also enabled on startup with default.target:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daemon Startup Target
Wants=recog-startup.service mpv-startup.service
After=recog-startup.service mpv-startup.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
Also=daemon-on.timer
```

daemon-off.target combines two shutdown services above:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daemon Shutdown Target
Wants=recog-shutdown.service mpv-shutdown.service
After=recog-shutdown.service mpv-shutdown.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot

[Install]
Also=daemon-off.timer
```

daemon-on.timer is set to trigger to trigger daemon-on.target at 9am:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daemon Startup Schedule

[Timer]
OnCalendar=9:00
Unit=recog-on.target
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

daemon-off.timer is set to trigger daemon-off.target at 23pm:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daemon Shutdown Schedule

[Timer]
OnCalendar=23:00
Unit=daemon-off.target
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

After placing all this under `~/.config/systemd/user/` I enable them in the following manner:

```
systemctl --user enable --now daemon-on.target
systemctl --user enable --now daemon-on.timer
systemctl --user enable --now daemon-off.timer
```

Which will autostart the daemon at each boot and here I expect the timers to start/stop the daemon according to the `OnCalendar=` option. At this point `systemctl --user list-timers` shows me that my two timers will trigger at the right times (please note that I set the timers only 3 minutes apart to save  waiting for ages):

```
NEXT                         LEFT         LAST                         PASSED    UNIT            ACTIVATES
Wed 2019-06-26 12:12:00 JST  1min 4s left Wed 2019-06-26 11:35:02 JST  35min ago daemon-off.timer daemon-off.target
Wed 2019-06-26 12:15:00 JST  4min 4s left Wed 2019-06-26 11:40:48 JST  30min ago daemon-on.timer  daemon-on.target
```

The off timer is then triggered and my daemon stops, after a few minutes the on timer is triggered and the daemon starts as predicted. However looking at the timers again, I see that they were reset and the NEXT/LEFT fields are set to n/a, and will never trigger the daemon again. What is the issue here?

```
NEXT LEFT LAST                         PASSED       UNIT            ACTIVATES
n/a  n/a  Wed 2019-06-26 12:12:06 JST  4min 18s ago daemon-off.timer daemon-off.target
n/a  n/a  Wed 2019-06-26 12:15:33 JST  50s ago      daemon-on.timer  daemon-on.target
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching a bit more and reading the systemd man pages I managed to simplify things a little and also get the desired behaviour of my services.

Firstly, I've had mistakes putting [Service] sections in my `.target` files, which didn't make sense. Secondly, I've discovered a `PartOf=` statement which allowed me to make a top level application with video player and recognition services as components. And lastly, by using `Conflicts=` option I could start/stop my application using two targets which conflict with each other. The `.timer`s attached to those targets will then flip-flop between each other, disabling or enabling my application chain and respective conflicting `.targets`. The result is still contained in 7 files, which is more than I would like to maintain, but it works as required.

app.service is the top level application, although it's a dummy, this could run something else:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
Also=app-on.timer app-off.timer
```

app-mpv.service is the video player component of the app and thus also depends on xorg:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Video Player Service
PartOf=app.service
After=app.service
Requires=xorg.target
After=xorg.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/videoplayer/app.py
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=app.service
```

app-recog.service is the image recognition component of the app and does not depend on the video player:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Recognition Service
PartOf=app.service
After=app.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/recog
ExecStart=/opt/recog/recog run
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=app.service
```

app-on.target is a virtual target, it becomes active as soon as the app-on.timer is triggered and in turn enables the app.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Startup Target
Conflicts=app-off.target
Wants=app.service
After=app.service
RefuseManualStart=yes

[Install]
Also=app-on.timer
```

app-off.target is a virtual target, it becomes active as soon as the app-off.timer is triggered and in turn disables the app.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Shutdown Target
Conflicts=app.service app-on.target
RefuseManualStart=yes

[Install]
Also=app-off.timer
```

app-on.timer simply triggers the app-on.target:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Startup Schedule

[Timer]
OnCalendar=9:00
Unit=app-on.target
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

app-off.timer simply triggers the app-off.target:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Shutdown Schedule

[Timer]
OnCalendar=23:00
Unit=app-off.target
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Enabling all this mess with (with the help of [this article](http://alesnosek.com/blog/2016/12/04/controlling-a-multi-service-application-with-systemd/)):

```
systemctl --user enable app app-mpv app-recog
systemctl --user enable --now app-on.timer app-off.timer
systemctl --user start app
```

The application starts running and if I check the timers, both of them are active and whichever comes first will be executed first:

```
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST PASSED UNIT            ACTIVATES
Wed 2019-06-26 14:00:00 JST  1min 25s left n/a  n/a    app-off.timer app-off.target
Wed 2019-06-26 14:01:00 JST  2min 25s left n/a  n/a    app-on.timer  app-on.target
```

After the off timer is triggered, it stops the application and the `app-off.target` but the on target remains scheduled:

```
NEXT                         LEFT     LAST                         PASSED  UNIT            ACTIVATES
Wed 2019-06-26 14:01:00 JST  55s left n/a                          n/a     app-on.timer  app-on.target
n/a                          n/a      Wed 2019-06-26 14:00:04 JST  3ms ago app-off.timer app-off.target
```

When the on timer is triggered, it starts the application and disables the `app-on.target`, but re-activates the off timer again:

```
NEXT                         LEFT     LAST                         PASSED  UNIT            ACTIVATES
Thu 2019-06-27 14:00:00 JST  23h left Wed 2019-06-26 14:00:04 JST  57s ago app-off.timer app-off.target
n/a                          n/a      Wed 2019-06-26 14:01:01 JST  5ms ago app-on.timer  app-on.target
```

And the cycle continues. I still doubt if this is the best way of configuring this and would love to hear other suggestions!